# Linq to Sql in ASP.Net MVC 4 returns actual query string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to get the First and Last Name string values out of my AspNetUsers table for a particuler record (ID). When I use Linq to Sql, it returns the entire sql query string. here is my code:

```
 var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var currentUser = from aspNetUser in db.AspNetUsers
                              where aspNetUser.Id == user
                              select aspNetUser.FirstName + " " + aspNetUser.LastName;
```

I am trying to populate my User Textbox in my View with the Current Users First and Last Name. Which I have added as columns to the AspNetUsers Table. Why does it return this ugly query and not someone's first and last name?

it's returning this:

```
SELECT     CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[FirstName] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[FirstName] END + N' ' + CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[LastName] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent1].[LastName] END AS [C1]    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure how you are getting the SQL query back, but you need a single record back from your query. Use First/FirstOrDefault like:

```
var currentUser = (from aspNetUser in db.AspNetUsers
                  where aspNetUser.Id == user
                  select aspNetUser.FirstName + " " + aspNetUser.LastName)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

`FirstOrDefault` would return the first record returned from the result. If there are no records then you will get `null` back.

You can also use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx)\ [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx), since you are querying against `ID` and there should always be a single record returned. But both of them could throw an exception if there are multiple records matching your criteria. Use any of them according to your requirement.

Comment: It was `FirstOrDefault`. Adding that gave me the First and Last Name of the User. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `FirstOrDefault()` to get single record against specific criteria:

```
var currentUser = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == user);

var Name = currentUser.FirstName + " " + currentUser.LastName;
```